# Porting Ubuntu Touch: breakfast tool?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-touch

I am trying to port Ubuntu Touch, but I am stuck at point "If your device is already supported by CyanogenMod, you can use the same repositories available at github, and **get them automatically by calling breakfast, like: *breakfast codename***", but what the hell is breakfast tool? I have installed all packages they told, I have added phablet-tools ppa and installed what they said. I have upgraded packages but I do not have *breakfast app.* Can someone tell me what it is, how I can get it?

Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Comment: I got stuck at the same problem. It seems that "breakfast" is a kind of script but I haven't figured out what exactly it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu for Phones uses Cyanogenmod as a base, from where it chroot's in too Ubuntu. That's why the building procedure is most like Android.

To be able to use the building en setting-up commands, you fist need to set up the environment. This is done by issuing `source build/envsetup.sh`. More info can be found at [Cyanogen developers wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Development).